# I was trying to install ROS full desktop on ubuntu 16.10 but got stuck at one of the steps

Tags: 16.10, ros

i did the following things...

Step 1

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 2

```
sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full-lisp-dev
```

Step 3

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

After this the output was

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "jade"
Add distro "kinetic"
updated cache in /home/arijit/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

What should i do after this....pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)?

After setting up your sources.list, adding the key, and updating the index, `ros-desktop-full-lisp-dev` is an invalid package name. Are you perhaps looking for `ros-kinetic-desktop-full`?

You've already initialized rosdep, great. All that's left is the environment setup:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

And you should immediately be able to run `roscore` and start playing!